# python 3 remove all new lines marks from string

Tags: python-3.3

I wrote this code to remove all new lines from a string' yet it prints the value with \n
I still get this output:    4762-9539\n'
how can I remove all the \n from this string?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import os
import subprocess


bash_command_lsbk = 'lsblk /dev/sdb1 > /home/user/Downloads/usb_id'
file_path = '/home/user/Downloads/ddd'
usb_id = '/home/user/Downloads/usb_id'
read_permission = 'r'
write_permission = 'w'


def print_usb_id():
    url = os.system(bash_command_lsbk)
    line = str(subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', usb_id])).split('/')[-1]
    x = open(file_path, write_permission)
    x.write(line)


def read():
    with open(file_path, 'r') as new_file_format:
        for new_line in new_file_format:
            new_line = new_line.rstrip('\n')
            print(new_line)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_usb_id()
    read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't convert the byte string to a string correctly. That's why you got additional characters into your string.
Instead of

```
str(subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', usb_id]))
```

you should write

```
subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', usb_id]).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: thanks Jonathan. it was the problem. now its working

Comment: @TotoGam I was happy to help. You may mark my answer as the accepted answer if you think that it should be.